# Linux find subdomain nameservers

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can i find the nameservers of subdomains ? Is there any way to find it ? I need that because the users enter the subdomains with other extensions.

For example:

```
test.test.com.au
test1.test.com
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `dig -t ns <subdomain>`